# how to assign different color map for different group of nodes in networkx

Tags: networkx

I'm trying to draw network using python3 `networkx` module.
Specifically, it is the job of assigning colors to nodes, edge drawing is not yet considered.

Sample network consists of three groups ('EU','NA','AS') and there are 2 or 3 elements for each group like belows.

EU : ['UK', 'FR', 'GE']      <---- node color : red

NA : ['US', 'CA']            <---- node color : blue

AS : ['JP', 'CN', IN']       <---- node color : green

I have set different drawing layout and assigned different color for each group of nodes and drawn the nodes with different size based on their 'landsize' attribute. I have attached image I drawn.

However, I would like to assign not solid color but color map for each groups.

For example, as for EU, assign not red but plt.cm.Reds, as as for NA, assign plt.cm.Blues.

(In this case color map range is based on the size of nodes.)

Is there any way to assign different color map for different group of nodes?

thanks for reading.

[image]

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([
    ('UK', {'reg' : 'EU', 'color' : 'red', 'landsize' : 241}),
    ('FR', {'reg' : 'EU', 'color' : 'red', 'landsize' : 547}),
    ('GE', {'reg' : 'EU', 'color' : 'red', 'landsize' : 348}),
    ('US', {'reg' : 'NA', 'color' : 'blue', 'landsize' : 9147}),
    ('CA', {'reg' : 'NA', 'color' : 'blue', 'landsize' : 9093}),
    ('JP', {'reg' : 'AS', 'color' : 'green', 'landsize' : 364}),
    ('CN', {'reg' : 'AS', 'color' : 'green', 'landsize' : 9388}),
    ('IN', {'reg' : 'AS', 'color' : 'green', 'landsize' : 2973})
    ])

eu_pos = nx.spring_layout(G.subgraph(['UK','FR','GE']), k =0.01)
na_pos = nx.random_layout(G.subgraph(['US','CA']))
as_pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G.subgraph(['JP','CN','IN']))

my_pos = {i : nx.spring_layout(G.subgraph([node for node, attr in G.nodes(data = 'reg') if attr == i])) for i in ['EU','NA','AS']}

new_pos = {}

new_pos.update({node : (pos[0], pos[1]) for node, pos in my_pos['EU'].items()})
new_pos.update({node : (pos[0], pos[1]) for node, pos in my_pos['NA'].items()})
new_pos.update({node : (pos[0], pos[1]) for node, pos in my_pos['AS'].items()})


nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, new_pos, node_size =  [c for n,c in G.nodes(data='landsize')], node_color = [c for n,c in G.nodes(data='color')])
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, new_pos, font_color = 'white')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make several calls to [`nx.draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html).
In each call you draw one of the regions (with the respective colormap). I was so free to select "Greens" for "AS".

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([
    ('UK', {'reg': 'EU', 'color': 'red', 'landsize': 241}),
    ('FR', {'reg': 'EU', 'color': 'red', 'landsize': 547}),
    ('GE', {'reg': 'EU', 'color': 'red', 'landsize': 348}),
    ('US', {'reg': 'NA', 'color': 'blue', 'landsize': 9147}),
    ('CA', {'reg': 'NA', 'color': 'blue', 'landsize': 9093}),
    ('JP', {'reg': 'AS', 'color': 'green', 'landsize': 364}),
    ('CN', {'reg': 'AS', 'color': 'green', 'landsize': 9388}),
    ('IN', {'reg': 'AS', 'color': 'green', 'landsize': 2973})
])

eu_pos = nx.spring_layout(G.subgraph(['UK', 'FR', 'GE']), k=0.01)
na_pos = nx.random_layout(G.subgraph(['US', 'CA']))
as_pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G.subgraph(['JP', 'CN', 'IN']))

my_pos = {i: nx.spring_layout(G.subgraph([node for node, attr in G.nodes(data='reg') if attr == i])) for i in
          ['EU', 'NA', 'AS']}

new_pos = {}

new_pos.update({node: (pos[0], pos[1]) for node, pos in my_pos['EU'].items()})
new_pos.update({node: (pos[0], pos[1]) for node, pos in my_pos['NA'].items()})
new_pos.update({node: (pos[0], pos[1]) for node, pos in my_pos['AS'].items()})

for group, colormap in [("EU", "Reds"), ("NA", "Blues"), ("AS", "Greens")]:
    nodelist = [node for node in G if G.nodes[node]["reg"] == group]
    node_sizes = [G.nodes[node]["landsize"] for node in nodelist]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,
                           new_pos,
                           node_color=node_sizes,
                           nodelist=nodelist,
                           node_size=node_sizes,
                           cmap=pl.get_cmap(colormap))
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, new_pos, font_color='white')
pl.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. And I'm sorry for not explaining exactly what I want. I meant setting the color range based on rank, not the land size itself. Nevertheless I adjusted it, the color range has changed significantly. I intended gradational color changes. However, I think it can be easily fixed by setting vmax and vmin options.
Thanks you again.